# Which timer does the setSoTimeout method in java change?

Tags: java, sockets

Is it the Re-transmission,Keep-alive,Persistence,Time-Wait Timer,ect? Also does udp use the same timers as tcp, if not what timers does udp use?

Answer (score 1):

It does not change a timer (which is something like a clock), it changes a timeout (which is a timespan to wait for something).

[The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) explains it quite well: it clearly says that `read()` operations on a socket are affected.

And since it is an instance method, it applies to that Socket instance only on which the call is made.